# Beautiful logical combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics, logic

TV series were aired for 5 years. Every day at most 2 episodes were shown.

Every year, starting from the second one, either 40% more, or 40% less episodes, than the previous year, were aired.

The 1230th episode was aired one day, and in exactly 2 years the last episode was shown.

How many episodes were aired in total for those 5 years?

How do we do this? I've tried considering cases of the first day and to derive from it cases for the next days, and then there's just so much cases for the following years and days, and also all other conditions need to be matched, how is it done?

Comment: Hint: each year the total number of episodes is multplied by either $\frac75$ or $\frac35$. In particular, the number of episodes in the first year must be a multiple of $5^4=625$, so that the number of episodes in the fifth year is an integer.

Comment: @GregMartin That's cool! So let's assume the minimum construction: 625 came out the first year, then if the second year 475 were aired, 285 the third, then it's already 1385 episodes, but it says on the last day of the third year it was 1230 episodes. How is it possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: It does not say the the last day of the third year, just some time in the third year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

- Each year the number of episodes is $\frac{7}{5}$ or $\frac{3}{5}$ times the previous year.  This tells you that the first year had a multiple of a certain power of $5$ episodes
- Each year had no more than $366 \times 2 = 732$ episodes.  You can now work out how many episodes there were in the first and second years.
- The $1230$th episode was shown in the third year. You can now work out how many episodes were shown in the third and fourth years.
- The calculation for the fifth year is harder, but there are only two possibilities and only one of these could have all the episodes shown so the last one is the same day of the year as the $1230$th was in the third year.
- Add up the numbers of episodes each year

Comment: I got 625 375 525 315 but totally stuck on the fifth. What is it?

Comment: The $1230$th episode is episode $230$ of the third year, with another $295$ to follow it, so it must have been before shown by the $366-295/2 = 219$th day. There were be $189$ or $441$ episodes in the fifth year, but you cannot have $441$ episodes in $219$ days, so the fifth year had $189$ episodes.

Comment: Wow that's neat thanks